# Why R+G+B is not equal white color?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, video-processing, camera-calibration

I am trying to implement colors calibration feature. It captures using camera a TV screen playing calibration footage (white, then red, then green the blue). 
I find points with max intensity of each color, so I got:

White (209, 209, 208)

Red   (130,2,1)

Green (0,190,2)

Blue  (0,1,95)

I disabled all automatic features in camera. I think, I should get something like these values:

Red   (209,2,1)

Green (0,209,2)

Blue  (0,1,208)

I know that camera has non linear characteristics of spectrum sensitivity, but I set gain of each channel manually to get a pure white and it should  also affect to separate RGB channels.
Any ideas why it happen and how to compensate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it it makes total sense.

Let me try to explain:

Your display has three kinds of elements. red, green and blue ones.

Let R,G and B be the "amount of light" emitted by each of those elements.

When you display a white image the amount of light emitted is `W = R + G + B`

So a red, green or blue image can never be as bright as a white image.

The differences between R, G and B are caused by the difference in emitter brightness and camera sensitivity.

Also your display will most likely change color gains when displaying white so don't expect the sum of R G and B to equal W